# Quickly testing freemarker expressions

Tags: freemarker

Today I was faced with the prospect of writing quite a few freemarker expressions. While the overall difficulty is not high, some of them will contain quite a few builtin calls (i.e. parsing formatted string to number, increasing it and formatting again).

That got me to thinking - how can I test that for development purpuses only to minimize the time spent? I know there are IDE tools that help with the syntax - however, **what about testing the functionality I wrote on sample strings**? Something that would allow me to parse `${"  b lah"?trim}` and check whether the output is what I expect? Running my app is obviously a possibility, but in my case it takes way too long to get to the part where using freemarker happens.

Comment: Are you using FreeMarker to generate HTML for a servlet? If so, you are wanting to check that your servlet servers the correct HTML.

Comment: Nope, I'm using freemarker as a mean to insert fields from database into .odt files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a simple JUnit test to test that.

Example:

```
public class FreemarkerSandbox {

   @Test
   public void testFreemarker() throws TemplateException, IOException {
      Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
      Template template = cfg.getTemplate("trim.ftl", CharEncoding.UTF_8);
      HashMap<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

      Writer out = new StringWriter();
      template.process(model, out);

      assertEquals("b lah", out.toString());
   }
}
```

With trim.ftl just containing the expression to test.

```
${"  b lah"?trim}
```

It can be improved by passing the test cases in the model.

Comment: Or if you don't want to create an `.ftl` file for each test: `new Template("adhoc", "${'  b lah'?trim}", cfg);`